# Redmon & capturing stdin with Delphi

Tags: delphi, console-application

I am using [redmon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/) to redirect postscript to delphi for processing.

I am using the following code to read stdin to a file:

```
var
  Stdin: THandleStream;
  FStream: TFileStream;
  BytesRead:Int64;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of Byte; 

StdIn := THandleStream.Create(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
try
  tempps:=GetTempFile('.ps');
  FStream:=tfilestream.Create(tempps,fmCreate or fmOpenReadWrite);
  StdIn.Seek(0,0);
  try
    repeat
      BytesRead:=StdIn.Read(Buffer,1024);
      FStream.Write(Buffer,BytesRead);
    until bytesread<SizeOf(Buffer);
  finally
    InputSize:=FStream.Size;
    FStream.Free;
  end;
finally
  StdIn.Free;
end;
```

This works for most cases, except one where the redmon log file shows:

```
REDMON WritePort: OK  count=65536 written=65536

REDMON WritePort: Process not running. Returning TRUE.
    Ignoring 65536 bytes
```

Is the fact that it's 65536 just a red herring, and it's that I'm not properly reading stdin, or is there some weird limit somewhere I've overlooked?

Thanks in advance.

## Edit 1

The 65536 is a red herring - redmon prints this message every 64k in the log, the entire file is 688759 bytes, however is does look like redmon closes output early, but then still continues to output more text anyway.

Comment: Time for some basic debugging. Did your process run at all? If so, how much data did it read? How much was it supposed to read? Does Redmon frequently generate *exactly* 64 KB of data?

Comment: Please interpret the redmon log for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how RedMon works, but I would not rely on `bytesread<SizeOf(Buffer)` as EOF condition, because I suppose you are actually reading from a pipe, and `ReadFile` function as MSDN documentation says can return the number of bytes read less than the number of bytes to read if you are reading from a pipe.

`BytesRead <= 0` condition is more reliable (it can fail only if RedMon will write 0 bytes on the other side of the pipe, I suppose it should not do it):

```
repeat
  BytesRead:=StdIn.Read(Buffer,1024);
  if BytesRead > 0 then
    FStream.WriteBuffer(Buffer,BytesRead);
until BytesRead <= 0;
```